# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement on to_date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, to-date, ora-00900

I get an error in a INSERT. The problem is in this line:

```
to_date('05-JUN-13 01.09.10.000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF')
```

I don't know how resolve it. I tried also with

```
to_timestamp('05-JUN-13 01.09.10.000000 PM','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF')
```

But i had this error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Any helps? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AM/PM format is missing, therefore the "date format picture" (what a wonderful name!) ends too early. Just use

> to_timestamp('05-JUN-13 01.09.10.000000 PM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF6 AM')

Comment: Perfect but now i get this one: `ORA-01502: index 'My_tab' or` `partition of such index is in unusable state`

Comment: If you get the 'index unusable' error, the index needs to be rebuild. I am not too clear why you get the error. Can you post your statement?

Comment: I apologize for my delay in answering. However now everything goes well thank you :)